# Why i Have this type of Failed Download when i Create a project in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

[Image Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VztOT.png)

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVRXZ.png)

Failed to download doctrine/inflector from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Now trying to download from source

- Syncing doctrine/inflector (2.0.8) into cache
  Failed to download doctrine/lexer from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing doctrine/lexer (3.0.0) into cache
  Failed to download symfony/polyfill-ctype from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.28.0) into cache
  Failed to download webmozart/assert from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing webmozart/assert (1.11.0) into cache
  Failed to download dragonmantank/cron-expression from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.3.3) into cache
  Failed to download symfony/deprecation-contracts from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.3.0) into cache
  Failed to download psr/container from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing psr/container (2.0.2) into cache
  Failed to download fakerphp/faker from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing fakerphp/faker (v1.23.0) into cache
  Failed to download symfony/polyfill-php80 from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.28.0) into cache
  Failed to download symfony/polyfill-php83 from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing symfony/polyfill-php83 (v1.28.0) into cache
  Failed to download symfony/polyfill-mbstring from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the version of laravel you are trying to install in supported by your current computer setup

Make sure you have these:

On Mac:

```
Latest Version of Composer
Latest version of php 
Latest version of node
```

On Windows:

```
Latest Version of xampp, node and composer
```

**Small Suggestion:** Use VS Code Terminal instead of command prompt (If you are on Windows)

After you satisfy all these requirements

Create New laravel project with following command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname
```

If you still encounter issues use the following command to ignore the platform requirements:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This should solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're facing troubles installing or updating packages with Composer in XAMPP due to missing zip-related tools and extensions. To fix this, follow these steps:

1. **Enable Zip Extension**:

   Open your XAMPP installation folder, go to the "php" directory, and locate the php.ini file. Look for the line containing extension=php_zip.dll and remove the semicolon at the beginning to enable the extension.
2. **Install 7-Zip**:

   If you're using Windows, download and install 7-Zip from its official website: https://www.7-zip.org/.
3. **Install Unzip (Unix-like systems)**:

   For Unix-like systems (Linux, macOS), use your package manager to install unzip. For example, on Ubuntu, you can run: sudo apt-get install unzip.
4. **Restart XAMPP**:

   After making changes, restart your XAMPP server.

Now, you should be able to run Composer without issues:

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?